# .html and .htm for xcode 4.3.2 (phonegap)

Tags: iphone, html, xcode, ios5

What is the difference when using **.html** and **.htm** for xcode 4.3.2 (phonegap)? I've files that will not create an app via xcode. I noticed it is .htm as I'm trying out a template file?

What is a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.htm` extension is a convention used for storing HTML documents on FAT16 filesystems (as used by DOS 6 and earlier).

`.html` is the convention for all other systems.

Presumably PhoneGap doesn't expect HTML documents to have the DOS file extension as it was created over a decade after such systems fell out of common usage.

Comment: Can you clarify "PhoneGap doesn't expect HTML documents to have the DOS file extension"?

Comment: @Irishgirl — Given the context provided by the previous two paragraph, I'm not sure what is unclear about the statement.